# Three.js - How to position objects around a sphere (globe)

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation, position

I have a json file of country borders that I'm using to build a map in three.js ([mbostock example](https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/geojson-in-three-js)).
What I would like is for the position of each cylinder to be mapped to its respective country- like this:
[image]

Please take a look at the following snippet. Currently I'm taking the center of the bounding box of each geometry, which is working well enough, but the cylinders are not pointing outwards as in the image. I have tried using lookAt() but it doesn't have the right effect. There is also a for loop that rotates my the countries and the cylinders, but they don't move as they should (uncomment it to test).

How can I position the cylinders correctly?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div id='my_dataviz'></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson-client@3"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-array@1"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-collection@1"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-dispatch@1"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-request@1"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-timer@1"></script>
<script type='module'>
import * as THREE from "https://unpkg.com/three@0.127.0/build/three.module.js";
import {OrbitControls} from "https://unpkg.com/three@0.127.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

var width1 = 860,
    height1 = 860,
    radius = 168,
    mesh,
    graticule,
    scene = new THREE.Scene,
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, width1 / height1, 1, 1000),
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true}),
    container = document.getElementById( 'my_dataviz' ),
    controls;

    camera.position.z = 400;
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(width1, height1);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(98, 52, 36 );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: "rgb(220,229,229)", opacity:0.7, transparent: true} );
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

d3.json("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/world-atlas@2/countries-50m.json", function(error, topology) {
  if (error) throw error;
  var countries = []
  var cones = []
  for (var i = 0; i < topology.objects.countries.geometries.length; i++) {
    var rgb = [];
    var newcolor;
    for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      rgb.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255));
      newcolor = 'rgb('+ rgb.join(',') +')';
    }
    var mesh = wireframe(topojson.mesh(topology, topology.objects.countries.geometries[i]), new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color:newcolor, linewidth: 5}))
    countries.push(mesh);
    scene.add(mesh);

    mesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox()
var center = new THREE.Vector3();
mesh.geometry.boundingBox.getCenter(center)

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, i/10, 1 );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: newcolor} );
const cone = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
cone.position.x = center.x;
cone.position.y = center.y;
cone.position.z = center.z;

// cone.lookAt(mesh.position);
cones.push(cone);
scene.add( cone );
  }
  console.log(sphere.position)

  scene.add(sphere);
  controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
  d3.timer(function(t) {
    for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
      // countries[i].rotation.x = Math.sin(t / 21000) * Math.PI / 3 - Math.PI / 2;
      // countries[i].rotation.z = t / 20000;
      // cones[i].rotation.x = Math.sin(t / 21000) * Math.PI / 3 - Math.PI / 2;
      // cones[i].rotation.z = t / 20000;
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
  });
});

// Converts a point [longitude, latitude] in degrees to a THREE.Vector3.
function vertex(point) {
  var lambda = point[0] * Math.PI / 180,
      phi = point[1] * Math.PI / 180,
      cosPhi = Math.cos(phi);
  return new THREE.Vector3(
    radius * cosPhi * Math.cos(lambda),
    radius * cosPhi * Math.sin(lambda),
    radius * Math.sin(phi)
  );
}

// Converts a GeoJSON MultiLineString in spherical coordinates to a THREE.LineSegments.
function wireframe(multilinestring, material) {
  var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry;
  var pointsArray = new Array();
  multilinestring.coordinates.forEach(function(line) {
    d3.pairs(line.map(vertex), function(a, b) {
      pointsArray.push(a,b);
    });
  });
  geometry.setFromPoints(pointsArray);
  return new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, material);
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groups!!

The cylinders were not rotating around the correct origin.

```
let earthPivot = new THREE.Group(); //this is what matters
    mesh.add( earthPivot ); //'mesh' is the globe
      const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1+i/10, 1 );
      const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: newcolor} );
      const cone = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
      cone.position.x = center.x;
      cone.position.y = center.y;
      cone.position.z = center.z;

      cones.push(cone);
      earthPivot.add( cone ); //this is what matters
```

Group your objects and add the group to the mesh you want your objects to rotate around.